# Copy Entity Framework Artifacts On BUild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, entity-framework-4, build

I have generated an EF4 model from database, and now I have EDMX file. 
In my solution, I have project called MyModel, which contains mentioned EDMX file, and another project called MyLogic, which references MyModel. And also I have MyGUI project, which consumes classes from MyLogic (i.e., references it).

For some reasons, I **must** have EF metadata to be deployed on disk, in separate csdl/ssdl/msl files, so I have set the "Metadata  Artifacts Processing" to "Copy to Output directory".
And yes, in MyProject\bin\Debug the EDM folder is generated, which contains these artifact files.

But this folder and artifacts does not get copied to the output dir of referencing project, i.e. MyLogic! And of course, they don't get copied into MyGUI.

What kind of magic do I need to force Visual Studio 2010 copy these files?